# Can concavity change in the interval between extrema points?

Tags: calculus

Apologies in advance for a basic question, but while doing the assignment for my university I came across a task to find extrema points in a polynomial function and justify them being minima, maxima or an inflection point.

Back from my high school knowledge I recalled that to do that, one can sample the value of second derivative in the intervals between the extrema points, to determine the concavity change.

However in this particular case one of the intervals seem to contain a value which when plugged into second derivative results in zero, and hence implies concavity changes there. With that said this point was not one of the roots of the first derivative. Moreover the degree of the derivative suggests there cannot be a 3rd root.

I'm curious whether concavity can change in the interval between two roots of the first derivative of a function, or did i make a calculational mistake? And if it can be the case - what is the property of that value if any?

Update:

As requested here is the exact issue I came across:

$p(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 5x -3$

$p`(x) = 3x^2 - 2x - 5$

roots of $p`(x)$ are:
$1, -\frac{5}{3}$.

$p``(x) = 6x - 2$

For my sampling values i choose: $ 2 > 1, 1 > 0.5 > -\frac{5}{3}, -2 < -\frac{5}{3}$, and here i came to realize that $f``(x) = 0$ when x is $\frac{1}{3}$ which is not one of the roots of the previous derivative.

It is confusing as it seems that concavity definitely changes in that interval, but i though for concavity can only change at one of the extrema points.

Comment: A zero of the second derivative does not necessarily imply that the concavity changes. Also the sign of the second derivative can change in an interval between two roots of the first derivative. – I suggest that you show a *concrete example* of what you calculated and what confuses you about it.

Comment: @MartinR I've updated the question, hope it is discrete enough now

Comment: Certainly concavity can change. It's called a *point of inflection*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the answer, i forgot that p.o.i is not a root on first derivative. If you can post the answer i could accept it, else i guess ill close this question since its figured out.

Comment: Done, as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculations are fine, and concavity can certainly change between zeroes of the first derivative. Where concavity changes is called a *point of inflection*.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations are not fine. Roots of p' are $-1$ and $\frac53$. Maybe that's where the confusion comes from. Here is the graph of p where the change of concavity occurs for $A=(\frac13,-\frac{128}{27})$. A directing vector of the tangent is $(3,-16)$.[image]. We have $\frac13$ which is between $-1$ and $\frac53$. Here is the graph of p':[image: graph of p']